# Persisting this object doesn't persist its parameters

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

Here are my entities ForfaitGenerique and Offre . Those two entities are in persistence.xml (didn't put all the methods here, if needed I will add more information):

```
@Entity
public class ForfaitGenerique implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int idForfait;

@NotNull
private String description = "description";


@NotNull
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "forfaitGenerique")
private List<Offre> listeOffre;

@NotNull
@ElementCollection
List<Integer> listeRemontees;
//erreur sur mon intellij mais pas d'erreur en faisant mvn clean install.On verra au test

public ForfaitGenerique() {

}
public void addOffre(Offre o) {
    this.listeOffre.add(o);
}

[...]

@Entity
public class Offre implements Serializable {

@NotNull
private AgeEnum age;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@NotNull
private double nbJour;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@NotNull
private SaisonEnum saison;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@NotNull
private ReductionEnum reduction;

boolean consecutif; 

@NotNull
private double prix;

@ManyToOne
private ForfaitGenerique forfaitGenerique;

public Offre() {
}
```

Here is what I am trying to persist a ForfaitGenerique ; when I persist it and then try to retrieve it through its id (which isn't null and seems to have a good value), I get a ForfaitGenerique, which is not null, but ALL stuff it should contain is null (not the id though) :

```
@EJB(name="databaseAccess") protected ForfaitsInterface databaseAccess;
private ForfaitGenerique f;
private Offre offre_f;
[...]
  ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
    l.add(1);
    l.add(2);
    l.add(3);

    ForfaitGenerique forf = new ForfaitGenerique();
    List<Offre> l_o = new ArrayList<Offre>();
    forf.setListeOffre(l_o);
    forf.setListeRemontees(l);
    Offre o = new Offre(forf,AgeEnum.ADULTE,0.5,SaisonEnum.HAUTE,ReductionEnum.FIDELICIME,true,12.0);
    forf.addOffre(o);
    databaseAccess.addForfaitGenerique(forf);
    int id_f = forf.getIdForfait();
    assertNotNull(id_f);
    System.out.println("bloublou"+id_f);
    f = databaseAccess.getForfaitGenerique(id_f);
    assertNotNull(f);
    assertNotNull(f.getListeRemontees());//null !!

    assertNotNull(f.getListeOffre());//null !!
    assertEquals(f,forf);
    offre_f = f.getListeOffre().get(0);
```

The databaseAccess object contains an entitymanager and two methods (among other), which are :

```
@Stateless(name="databaseAccess")
public class Forfaits implements ForfaitsInterface {
@PersistenceContext private EntityManager entityManager;

public void addForfaitGenerique(ForfaitGenerique forfaitGenerique) {
    entityManager.persist(forfaitGenerique);
    System.out.println("contains = "+entityManager.contains(forfaitGenerique));
}

@Override
public void addOffre(Offre o) {
    entityManager.persist(o);
}

public ForfaitGenerique getForfaitGenerique(int id_forfait)  {
    ForfaitGenerique f = entityManager.find(ForfaitGenerique.class,id_forfait);//database.getForfaitFromId(id_forfait);
    return f;
}
```

I think that my problem is when I am trying to persist my object, but not sure . Any help is appreciated .

Comment: What do you see in the database? Are the entities saved into DB?

Comment: I guess so, because the "find" gives me a not notnull ForfaitGenerique ;at some point  I tried to throw an exception if the retrieved object isn't in the database, but I got no exception ; so I guess that this entity is stored in the database ; I have also other entities which are stored and retrieved with no problem.

Comment: Can you post the console output of `id_f;` before and after the call to `databaseAccess.addForfaitGenerique(forf);`?

Comment: Do you have `@JoinColumn` annotation with `@ManyToOne` annotation in other entities where persisting **lists** work?

Comment: What is the goal of @JoinColumn ? I am not using it anywhere, since it is the only class where I have lists ... And I guess this is the problem x)

Answer (score 0):

In fact I just forgot to add the @Transactional(TransactionMode.COMMIT) before my test . That was the dumb solution.